# parsing data from vk.com by angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, vk

I try to get first and last name from www.vk.com. 
I have the address with my id - 
"https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=146133434&v=5.52"
and use $http.get, but don't get result.
But if I get and save json file from address line, the script works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
            {{x.first_name+ ' ' +  x.last_name }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("data.json", {header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=windows-1251'}})
//        $http.get("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=146133434&v=5.52",   // not working
//        {header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}})
            .then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.response;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file saved from "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=146133434&v=5.52"

```
{"response":
     [{
         "id":146133434,
         "first_name":"Vadim",
         "last_name":"Opolski"}
     ]}
```

Comment: check api documentation, you have probably to auth somehow.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution for your problem. This is a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" problem. The api.vk.com does not allow you to request it directly from a browser. You have to pass throw your server to get the data.